# igraph get ids of connected components

Tags: r, igraph

How can I access the ids of the top3 connected components of a graph in `igraph`?

```
c <- igraph::components(g, mode = 'weak')
which(c$membership == which.max(c$csize))
```

will give the largest
and

```
which(c$membership == which.max(c$csize-1))
```

the same result as `c$csize-1` will just subtract -1 from all values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `order` to sort and find out the memberships of the top 3 largest clusters and use `%in%` to check if vertices are within one of them:

```
which(c$membership %in% order(c$csize, decreasing = TRUE)[1:3])
```

---

- `order(c$csize, decreasing = TRUE)` gives the index(which corresponds to the cluster id) that will sort the `size` in descending order;
- `c$membership` contains the cluster id for all vertices;
- use `%in%` to check if the cluster id are within the top three;

Answer (score 1):

You can extract the top 3 (in terms of size) components with `tail` and then loop over those values to get the members of the component.

```
top3 <- which(c$csize %in% tail(sort(c$csize),3) )
sapply(top3, function(x) which(c$membership == x))
```